# Rstudios - struggling to input the right coding

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I'm working with Rstudios and I do not know how to enter a code to replace one value with another. I have a vector of `(a, b, c)` and I need to change it to `(a, b, d)`. Sorry, basic question but I am a beginner!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Beginner questions are welcome, but often they have already been asked and answered before. I don't use R, but maybe this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[R]+change+element+of+a+vector) will help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a character vector as you have described above, `v <- c("a","b","c")`, in order to re-assign the third element you can type `v[3] <- "d"` to get the desired result. If `a,b,c,` and `d` are numeric then the quotes are unnecessary.